# How to aggregate mongoDB query to return an average occurrence with unique field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have similar to the following record in my table in the collection:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("<random_object_id>"),
  name: "event_1",
  userId: "<random_uuid>",
  createdAt: "<random_date>",
  data: {
    formatId: "<random_uuid>",
    <other properties>
  },
  <...other properties>
}
```

For each `formatId`, there will be such record with the name `event1`, for some of those `formatId`s there will be also a record with `event_2`.
My aim is to aggregate the collection in such a way that I return as a result for every `formatId` with a unique user the difference (average) between the records with `name: event_1` and `name: event_2` (`event_1` will always be with the bigger number) for a specific amount of time ($lg/$gt).

Example: format<1> occurs 5 times with `event_1` and 3 times with `event_2` for period X (filtered by unique users). The result for this `formatId` should be the ratio between `event_1` and `event_2` - in this case 60%, the result should also include the formatId.

```
[{
  _id: ObjectId("..."),
  average: 60%,
  ...
},
...
]
```

How would the query look like? (the language is node.js/typescript if this is important)

I tried something like:

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        name: { $in: { ['event_1', 'event_2'] } },
        createdAt: {
          $gte: new ISODate("2020-12-10"), // (just an example)
          $lt: new ISODate("2020-12-20") // (just an example)
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: `$data.formatId`,
        count: { $addToSet: "$userId" }, // unique users that appear in event_2 (they will 100% appear in event_1 as well)
        average: ....
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        count: {
          $size: "$count",
        },
        average: 1 // should be 60% in this case
      },
    },
    { $sort: { count: -1 } },
  ])
```

Comment: Your query is incomplete, complete it following the manual to the best of your ability.